# How to split string to multidimensional array for filling it to DataGridView

Tags: c#

I have to fill my datagridview from string that have delimiter "/" for rows then "|" for columns in each row

My Data Example`twinlock@yahoo.com|Let1337 | EX = 2022-11-13 | Remaining Days = 14/hkj@me.com|Padls1 | EX = 2023-08-10 | Remaining Days = 284/`

i want data to be split into thier respective columns

[image]

email in email section, password in password, in expiry date it should show only date in column like 2022-11-13 and remaining days should be automatically calculated from the current and the expiry date given in data.

Comment: How are `"|"` and `"/"` escaped if they occur in the real data?

Comment: Your input data contains remaining days, yet you're asking for it to be calculated. You need to read [ask] and then improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should split entire string by `/`, that way you will have a total amount of rows for your data.
Then for each row, split it by `|`, that way you will have columns for each row.

That could look something like:

```
var rows = data.Split("/");

foreach (var row in rows)
{
    var columns = row.Split("|");
}
```